# How to fetch Last Login Date of a Student using the Valence API of D2L

Tags: desire2learn

How do I fetch the last login date of a Student for a Course and the System in general using Valence API from D2L?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When asking questions here, you should be as specific as possible. Also, you should indicate what you have already tried to do regarding your problem

Answer (score 0):

Session data, such as login and logout times for LMS users, is not currently available through the Valence Learning Framework API.

Comment: Is there a chance that the capability could be added sometime soon?

Comment: Desire2Learn plans future enhancements based primarily on the expressed business cases of their customers (clients and development partners). Accordingly, if you make sure that your interest gets communicated to your coordinating D2L Account Manager or Partner Manager, then it can make its way into our product roadmap queue.